# How can I install and use powerline plugin?

Tags: software-installation, vim, prompt, powerline-plugin

[Powerline](https://powerline.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) is a plug-in to display informational and beautiful statusline for vim, tmux and shell prompt for bash, zsh.

**Vim statusline**:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
How can I install and setup Powerline for different applications and shells in Ubuntu?

Comment: Just as a note. My plugin was installed to dist-packages instead of site-packages so I had to point the applications to that directory instead. It seems to be a convention for debian-based distributions to be able to have more than one python installation configured. Anyways it took me a while to figure this out so I hope this can save you guys some headaches.

Comment: For your info: I have added a new, easier install method on 14.04.

Answer (score 247, accepted):

## Plugin Installation:

Install `python-pip` and `git`: Open terminal by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and run:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip git
```

- **Per user:**
  In terminal run:

  ```
  pip install --user git+git://github.com/Lokaltog/powerline
  ```

  Add `~/.local/bin` to `$PATH` by modifying `~/.profile` with your favourite editor:

  ```
  gksudo gedit ~/.profile
  ```

  and adding following lines at the end of it:

  ```
  if [ -d "$HOME/.local/bin" ]; then
      PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
  fi
  ```
- **System wide:**
  In terminal run:

  ```
  su -c 'pip install git+git://github.com/Lokaltog/powerline'
  ```

## Font Installation:

Powerline provides two ways of installing the required fonts. If you're using one of following terminal: `Gnome Terminal`, `Konsole`, `lxterminal`, `st`, `Xfce Terminal`, `Terminator`, `Guake`, `Yakuake` then you should use *"Fontconfig"* method.

- **Fontconfig:** (recommended)

  - **Per User:**
    Run the following commands in terminal:

    ```
    wget https://github.com/Lokaltog/powerline/raw/develop/font/PowerlineSymbols.otf https://github.com/Lokaltog/powerline/raw/develop/font/10-powerline-symbols.conf
    mkdir -p ~/.fonts/ && mv PowerlineSymbols.otf ~/.fonts/
    fc-cache -vf ~/.fonts
    mkdir -p ~/.config/fontconfig/conf.d/ && mv 10-powerline-symbols.conf ~/.config/fontconfig/conf.d/
    ```
  - **System wide:**
    Run the following commands in terminal:

    ```
    wget https://github.com/Lokaltog/powerline/raw/develop/font/PowerlineSymbols.otf https://github.com/Lokaltog/powerline/raw/develop/font/10-powerline-symbols.conf
    sudo mv PowerlineSymbols.otf /usr/share/fonts/
    sudo fc-cache -vf
    sudo mv 10-powerline-symbols.conf /etc/fonts/conf.d/
    ```
- **Patched font:**
  Use this method only if *"Fontconfig"* method doesn't work for you or you're using a terminal other than mentioned above.

  1. Download the font of your choice from [powerline-fonts](https://github.com/Lokaltog/powerline-fonts).
  2. Move your patched font to `~/.fonts/` for per user installation or `/usr/share/fonts` for system wide installation.
  3. Run `fc-cache -vf ~/.fonts` to update your font cache, `sudo fc-cache -vf` to do it system wide.

To use patched font in `Gvim` see this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/3532/37006) and to change the font of your respective terminal check this question: [How to change the font of various terminal emulators?](https://askubuntu.com/q/283830/37006). You may have to reboot your system after font installation for changes to take effect.

## Usage: (for per user installation)

- **Vim statusline:**
  Add following to your `~/.vimrc` or `/etc/vim/vimrc`:

  ```
  set rtp+=$HOME/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/powerline/bindings/vim/

  " Always show statusline
  set laststatus=2

  " Use 256 colours (Use this setting only if your terminal supports 256 colours)
  set t_Co=256
  ```
- **Bash prompt:**
  Add the following line to your `~/.bashrc` or `/etc/bash.bashrc`:

  ```
  if [ -f ~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/powerline/bindings/bash/powerline.sh ]; then
      source ~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/powerline/bindings/bash/powerline.sh
  fi
  ```
- **Zsh prompt:**
  Add the following line to your `~/.zshrc` or `/etc/zsh/zshrc`:

  ```
  if [[ -r ~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/powerline/bindings/zsh/powerline.zsh ]]; then
      source ~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/powerline/bindings/zsh/powerline.zsh
  fi
  ```
- **Tmux statusline:**
  Add the following line to your `~/.tmux.conf`:

  ```
  source ~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/powerline/bindings/tmux/powerline.conf
  set-option -g default-terminal "screen-256color"
  ```

  If your terminal supports 256 colours, set `TERM` environment variable to `xterm-256color` by modifying `~/.bashrc` or `/etc/bash.bashrc` and adding following line:

  ```
  export TERM=xterm-256color
  ```

  To check if your terminal supports 256 colours check the documentation of your terminal or google it. Most popular terminals support 256 colours.

## Usage: (for system wide installation)

- **Vim statusline:**
  Add following to your `~/.vimrc` or `/etc/vim/vimrc`:

  ```
  set rtp+=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/powerline/bindings/vim/

  " Always show statusline
  set laststatus=2

  " Use 256 colours (Use this setting only if your terminal supports 256 colours)
  set t_Co=256
  ```
- **Bash prompt:**
  Add the following line to your `~/.bashrc` or `/etc/bash.bashrc`:

  ```
  if [ -f /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/powerline/bindings/bash/powerline.sh ]; then
      source /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/powerline/bindings/bash/powerline.sh
  fi
  ```
- **Zsh prompt:**
  Add the following line to your `~/.zshrc` or `/etc/zsh/zshrc`:

  ```
  if [[ -r /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/powerline/bindings/zsh/powerline.zsh ]]; then
      source /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/powerline/bindings/zsh/powerline.zsh
  fi
  ```
- **Tmux statusline:**
  Add the following line to your `~/.tmux.conf`:

  ```
  source /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/powerline/bindings/tmux/powerline.conf
  set-option -g default-terminal "screen-256color"
  ```

  If your terminal supports 256 colours, Set `TERM` environment variable to `xterm-256color` by modifying `~/.bashrc` or `/etc/bash.bashrc` and adding following line:

  ```
  export TERM=xterm-256color
  ```

  To check if your terminal supports 256 colours check the documentation of your terminal or google it. Most popular terminals support 256 colours.

## Configuration:

For detailed information on configuring `Powerline`: [Configuration](https://powerline.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration.html#).

## Uninstall:

To uninstall `Powerline` run one of following commands in terminal:

- To uninstall per user installation:

  ```
  pip uninstall powerline
  ```
- To uninstall system wide installation:

  ```
  su -c 'pip uninstall powerline'
  ```

<sub>Source: [Powerline beta documentation](https://powerline.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html)</sub>

## Alternatives:

If you're installing Powerline just for Vim you should try [vim-airline](https://github.com/bling/vim-airline) which is more customizable and lightweight.

Comment: It should probably also be mentioned that the user will need to set their emulator to "login" so that ~/.profile will be properly ran or they might run into issues with not being able to use their terminal when it's unable to find the powerline command.

Comment: Basharat Sial's answer is very good; however, when trying to have vim point to the package in the python library for the system wide install, the path that worked for me was: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/powerline/bindings/vim/ Basically just replace the `site-packages` with `dist-packages` wherever it appears for the "Usage" steps. Hope this helps anyone who runs into the same thing.

Comment: as pointed below, the installation path for system wide is `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/powerline/`. So at the vimrc you should point at `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/powerline/bindings/vim/` instead

Comment: @demil133 Fixed!

Comment: for me (on Ubuntu 12.04) per user font installation doesn't work I had to install fonts system wide

Comment: Finally setting this in .bashrc helped LANG=en_US.utf8.

Comment: No longer works in Ubuntu 15.04

Comment: Shouldn't Vim be compiled with Python support?

Comment: I have followed your solution line by line. But I am not getting the arrow symbols in [my bash terminal](https://postimg.org/image/gsh747e03/). But I was able to get them inside Vim. Please help, thanks.

Comment: Never mind, i found a solution:
  I added the following line:  

`export LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"`  

to my .bashrc . Earlier it was "en_IN"

Comment: Could you add the instructions for installing on the "Windows Linux Subsystem" ?

Comment: @TheLinuxEvangelist I still don't get arrow symbols on prompt after adding that line.

Comment: Please update the answer with latest changes.

Comment: @vikramreddym Follow all the steps in the answer and change the LC_TYPE it might be en_IN because of your region settings

Comment: @TheLinuxEvangelist, cc: @Anwar,  Finally it worked but not with what you suggested. First I ran `locale` to check the language and all the variables had `en_IN`. So I had to run `sudo locale-gen en_US en_US.UTF-8` and then I ran `sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales`. In the configuration menu, I have deselected en_IN using spacebar when it asked me to select which ones to regenerate and selected en_US-UTF-8 in the next menu. So thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Adding below line to .bashrc file works for me                                                        if [ -d "$HOME/.local/bin" ]; then
    PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
fi
export POWERLINE_COMMAND=powerline

if [ -f ~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/powerline/bindings/bash/powerline.sh ]; then
    source ~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/powerline/bindings/bash/powerline.sh
fi

Comment: For vim it works. But for `bash` I get the following error:  bash: /home/wolfgang/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/powerline/bindings/bash/../../../scripts/powerline-config: No such file or directory

Comment: Works on WSL (Ubuntu 18.04). This is the best explanation on internet for powerline installation and setup. Even better than the official docs :-D

Comment: in 19.04, powerline now uses Python 3 and the path has changed to (/usr/share/powerline/bindings/bash/powerline.sh)

Answer (score 36):

As of Ubuntu 14.10 (utopic), a `powerline` package is available in the [universe repository](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository). To install it, just run this command in your terminal :

`sudo apt-get install powerline`

Alternatively, you should be able to install it by using the Ubuntu Software Center.

Comment: This doesn't really solve my problem though. Is there anything else on top of this that needs to be performed for this to work?

Comment: Yes, there is, but it depends on how you want to use powerline. Instructions on how to integrate it in common applications are found in the package documentation located in `/usr/share/doc/powerline`. The relevant file in this package is [README.Debian](https://sources.debian.net/src/powerline/1.2-2/debian/README.Debian/).

Comment: If instruction is found in the doc, put them here. Otherwise it doesn't worth just writing the command to install it because installing doesn't do anything

Comment: It should be added that this method does not include bash bindings and many other bindings are missing.

Comment: All bindings are included in the `powerline` package, including bash bindings. They are installed in `/usr/share/powerline/bindings`.

Comment: Solved it for me after installing the font system wide.

Answer (score 28):

Though this has been answered, it seems the solution may also be somewhat overkill in terms of the installment for Bash at this point in time. Unaware am I if Powerline was available in the earlier repos, but it is available in the current repos. That being said, it's much less abstracted for Bash right now.

## Install Powerline using this command;

`sudo apt install powerline`

#### For per user configuration, edit your `.bashrc` with your text editor of choice.

`gedit ~/.bashrc`

And append this to the document;

```
if [ -f `which powerline-daemon` ]; then
  powerline-daemon -q
  POWERLINE_BASH_CONTINUATION=1
  POWERLINE_BASH_SELECT=1
  . /usr/share/powerline/bindings/bash/powerline.sh
fi
```

#### For system configuration, edit `/etc/bash.bashrc` as root with your text editor of choice.

`sudo su` followed by `gedit /bash.bashrc`

and append this to the document;

```
if [ -f `which powerline-daemon` ]; then
  powerline-daemon -q
  POWERLINE_BASH_CONTINUATION=1
  POWERLINE_BASH_SELECT=1
  . /usr/share/powerline/bindings/bash/powerline.sh
fi
```

Comment: Do I need to do anything else on Gnome Terminal?

Comment: This is the answered that worked for Ubuntu 21.04 too.

Answer (score 6):

## On 14.04 with the latest version of Powerline

With the latest install of powerline things have gotten a lot easier. Here is how I went about it.

1. Install Vundle and set it up in your .vimrc
2. Install [powerline](https://github.com/powerline/powerline) through the Vundle package installer
3. Install [the fonts](https://github.com/powerline/fonts) (just run the ./install.sh script).
4. Use the following settings in your .vimrc:

   ```
   Bundle 'Lokaltog/powerline', {'rtp': 'powerline/bindings/vim/'}
   " Powerline setup
   set laststatus=2
   set term=xterm-256color
   set termencoding=utf-8
   set guifont=Ubuntu\ Mono\ derivative\ Powerline:10
   " set guifont=Ubuntu\ Mono
   let g:Powerline_symbols = 'fancy'
   ```
5. Go into your `~/.vim/bundles/powerline/fonts` folder and double click the font that is in there. Install it.
6. (On some systems you need to copy the powerline font config to `/etc/fonts/conf.d`)
7. Log out and back in.

Note: you do not need to install it via pip anymore.

Comment: How does this method affect the availability of Powerline for use in shells, tmux, etc.?

Comment: @DennisWilliamson To be honest, I would not know as I have not used powerline in those contexts. Because all the configuration is vim specific, I could imagine that this does not affect the other contexts at all.

Comment: @don.joey According to the documentation, they should *not* be used side by side (see the warning box): https://powerline.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage/other.html#vim-statusline

Comment: @Andrew I am not sure I get your point. You mean you should not install both via Vundle and via pip? Because that is not what I am suggesting, right?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. Isn't that what you were suggesting? Vundle works for vim-only but if you want it in multiple places then instead install via pip only, then configure for vim.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want the bash extension, I wrote a small script that automates the manual steps that Basharat Sialvi wrote (many thanks for that complete reference).

In synthesis (but please, have a look at the script first as I won't be responsible if it throws your computer out of the window or delete your files):

```
git clone git@github.com:vincepii/ubuntu-powerline-bash.git
cd ubuntu-powerline-bash
./install.sh
```

https://thealarmclocksixam.wordpress.com/2016/02/28/quickly-setup-powerline-for-bash-in-ubuntu/

https://github.com/vincepii/ubuntu-powerline-bash

Comment: Hi, I have used your script file. But I am not getting the arrow symbols on [my bash terminal](https://postimg.org/image/gsh747e03/). Though I am getting them inside vim.

Comment: Never mind, i found a solution:
  I added the following line:  

`export LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"`  

to my .bashrc . Earlier it was "en_IN"