# Problem with tmux startup displaying running config. (powerline)

Tags: bash, tmux, powerline-plugin

I just installed powerline using this tutorial: https://askubuntu.com/a/283909/408189

Now, the first thing I see when I open tmux with the command
`tmux`is what looks like the running config.

What I want to see is a new bash shell (which I get by pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>).

Instead, this is what is displayed:

```
set option: status -> on                                                                      [0/0]
set option: status-utf8 -> on
set option: status-interval -> 2
set option: status-left-length -> 20
set option: status-right -> "#(env "$POWERLINE_COMMAND" $POWERLINE_COMMAND_ARGS tmux right -R pane"
set option: status-right-length -> 150
set option: window-status-format -> "#[fg=colour244,bg=colour233,nobold,noitalics,nounderscore]  #"
set option: window-status-current-format -> "#[fg=colour233,bg=colour31,nobold,noitalics,noundersc"
set option: status-left -> "#[fg=colour16,bg=colour254,bold,noitalics,nounderscore] #S #[fg=colour"
set option: status-fg -> colour231
set option: status-bg -> colour233
set option: window-status-fg -> colour249
set option: window-status-activity-attr -> none
set option: window-status-bell-attr -> none
set option: window-status-activity-fg -> colour11
set option: window-status-bell-fg -> colour1
```

The powerline theme is fully functional and everything else works after pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>.

This is the `.tmuxrc.conf` file I have:

```
source ~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/powerline/bindings/tmux/powerline.conf
set-option -g default-terminal "screen-256color"
```

Answer (score 1):

@Sander. I had the exact same issue when I first installed tmux-powerline, and upgrading tmux resolved the problem for me. My version prior to updating was 1.8, and I'm currently at 2.1.

Scroll to the bottom of [this page](https://github.com/ThomasAdam/tmux) for update instructions. I did my installation from the git repo. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue with running Powerline on tmux 1.8. See https://github.com/powerline/powerline/issues/1394.

The standard solution, as [@wrfc noted](https://askubuntu.com/a/637343/5682), is to upgrade tmux. The [pi-rho/dev PPA](https://launchpad.net/~pi-rho/+archive/ubuntu/dev) has new versions of tmux (and of other popular development tools) and seems to be popular. To use it:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pi-rho/dev
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install tmux
```

Since pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd>, or <kbd>Enter</kbd> clears the config, an alternate (hack) solution is to tell tmux to press that itself, by adding `send-key Enter` to your .tmux.conf.