# Fish Powerline with status line at the bottom of the shell

Tags: fish, powerline-plugin

I am trying to figure out how this guys manage to have the status line at the bottom of fish-shell as he shared here.

https://github.com/yongjhih/rc/blob/master/art/screenshot-fish-powerline.png

I setup powerline using instruction from this question

[How can I install and use powerline plugin?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/283908/how-can-i-install-and-use-powerline-plugin)

Thanks!

Comment: Or maybe the owner just using tmux -- fish without mentioned it. :)

Comment: so were you able to figure this out? I am happy with my prompt, but I want a status bar like they have in vim, but for my shell where I can put weather info or cpu/memory info etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After researched I came to conclude that it was not feature of fish-shell but a tmux session.

For more information about tmux powerline you can refer to this repo:

https://github.com/erikw/tmux-powerline