# Install powerline fonts from command line with a script

Tags: scripts

How can I check the conditions to install the powerline fonts in each of the ways outlined [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/283908/how-can-i-install-and-use-powerline-plugin)? I want to add this to a [configuration script](https://github.com/arturojosejr/post-install-script/blob/master/install/system-setup) I have.

```sh
if terminal == gnome  ||  terminal == ...; then
    Fontconfig method;
else
    git clone powerline fonts
    ./install
fi
```

Comment: what do you mean by "conditions"? all you need to do is follow the top answer? By the way: it might be better to ask in a comment to explain bits of the answer.

Comment: I want a script that installs the powerline fonts automatically? Why would I follow the top answer if what I want is a script that does that automatically?

Comment: Because the top answer would have included that script if there was one. And where in your question did you ask for a script to do this?