# How to get a a graphical BASH prompt?

Tags: command-line, bash, 19.04

I want something that looks like this:

[image]

Is there any way to achieve this?
If so, how can I do this?

NOTE: I use Kubuntu Disco in case that is important.

Comment: Check this out: https://ohmyz.sh and https://ohmybash.github.io/

Comment: And https://yalneb.blogspot.com/2018/01/fancy-bash-promt.html as well as search the 'net for fancy bash prompts.

Comment: The default bash prompt is specifically designed to be useful for scp/sftp commands - may want to consider that before changing it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Kubuntu 19.04, install *fonts-powerline* using `sudo apt install fonts-powerline`. Your system should also have *fonts-hack*.

Visit [this site](https://yalneb.blogspot.com/2018/01/fancy-bash-promt.html) and copy the entire script, all 348 lines as on 20190906, to *~/bin* and save it as *powerline.sh* or whatever. Use the file manager to make the script executable.

(Note that *~/bin* is by default in your system's path and so you do not need something like `$HOME/bin/.powerline.sh`.)

Open konsole and, from your home folder, run

```
echo "source powerline.sh" >> ~/.bashrc
```

Doing so will add

```
source powerline.sh
```

as the last line of your *~/.bashrc*.

From your still open konsole window, run

```
source .bashrc
```

to reload *.bashrc* and use *powerline.sh* in the existing konsole window.

If you want to go back to the default prompt, comment out the `source powerline.sh` line  in *~/.bashrc* by placing a `#` mark at the beginning of the line.

Read the contents of *~/bin/powerline.sh* if you want to modify some aspects of the prompt.

[image: konsole prompt using powerline fonts]

---

Konsole, whether in Kubuntu 19.04 or Kubuntu 18.04, doesn't need *fonts-powerline* installed. But other terminals such as *lxterminal* and *gnome-terminal* need the package to get the triangles and the prompt to display nicely.

Comment: Nice! However, you do need fonts-powerline for the triangles.

Comment: @vanadium I thought so as well but I checked again, I don't have `fonts-powerline` installed on Kubuntu 18.04 and still have the triangles. I also checked Lubuntu 19.04. There too, `fonts-powerline` is absent and the triangles are present. I don't know how the triangles are still being generated.

Comment: @vanadium, even `apt list --installed | grep -i powerline` comes up empty. Maybe it's needed on a GNOME-based system?

Comment: Could be. I had to install the fonts to have a good outcome.

Answer (score 4):

The appearance of the Bash command prompt is controlled by the environmental variable $PS1. By changing this environmental variable, you change the appearance of the prompt.

You can see the current setting of this variable with the command:

```
echo $PS1
```

The prompt can be changed with the command

```
PS1="<string representing new format>"
```

To change permanently, change the definition of PS1 in the file `.bashrc` in your home folder. That script is run automatically when you open a terminal, and includes a section where PS1 is defined.

`man bash` may instruct you about the syntax of the string that defines the prompt format. It may be easier, though, to start with some tutorials like here on [How-To Geek](https://www.howtogeek.com/307701/how-to-customize-and-colorize-your-bash-prompt/) or [nixcraft](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-linux-unix-bash-shell-setup-prompt.html).

To implement effects as appear in your screenshot, you may want to consider [Powerline](https://powerline.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html), a set of script developed to provide a more fancy look to the vim editor, but including scripts to change among others the bash terminal. Powerline can be installed with `sudo apt install powerline`, and can then be used according to the documentation.

For more details regarding installation and use, refer to [How can I install and use powerline plugin?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/283908/how-can-i-install-and-use-powerline-plugin), and in particular the answer of Schycken, because earlier answers have become obsolete.

Comment: I think OP wants something like powerline which apparently requires `fonts-powerline` installed.

Comment: @steeldriver Thank you for the comment. I updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

Visit [synth-shell](https://github.com/andresgongora/synth-shell) and follow the instructions there

in Ubuntu:

```
mkdir ~/bin
chmod +x ~/bin
cd ~/bin
sudo apt install fonts-powerline
git clone --recursive https://github.com/andresgongora/synth-shell.git
chmod +x synth-shell/setup.sh
cd synth-shell
./setup.sh
```

and then follow the prompts in your terminal. restart your terminal emulator. If you're not seeing the coloured arrows in your prompt then you may need to change your terminal's font to something like [hack-ttf](https://sourcefoundry.org/hack/) and check your locale is using UTF-8

Answer (score -3):

The simplest way: https://ohmyz.sh/

And choose a theme like this one: https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/wiki/Themes#agnoster

[image: ZSH theme]

Comment: How does installing a *Zsh* theme help getting a graphical *Bash* prompt?