# How to get inverted colour arrow on the username in the terminal?

Tags: command-line, gnome, gnome-terminal, gnome-shell, ubuntu-gnome

Please refer the attached image. I want an inverted colour arrow on the username part in the terminal.

This screenshot is taken from a Mac Terminal.
[image: Source Terminal Screenshot of the Terminal]

For the below image, i want an arrow on top the of the whole left side text(as in above image), starting from  dp0522 till the $(in the below image),
[image: Target Terminal Screenshot]

Comment: Could you please draw the desired output, our question is not 100% clear. Do you mean an orange arrow for example? Thanks.

Comment: There is no (obvious) user name part in the prompt you show, it seems to be just a path – please clarify.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CustomizingBashPrompt

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1171232/how-to-get-a-a-graphical-bash-prompt/ ?

Comment: @DKBose the above post is for Kubuntu, will it be applicable for ubuntu?

Comment: Yes, It's more about Bash than about the desktop environment.

Comment: @DKBose I just want the gui. I don't want _sh_ changing to _zsh_

Comment: Read the answer properly.

Comment: Thanks for the help.This exactly didn't address my requirements. Anyway i found a detailed guide at [link](https://linuxhint.com/install_zsh_shell_ubuntu_1804/)